# android list view adapter call getview method manually (to refresh list rows)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

Is it posibble to call the getview method in the list view adapter to refresh the rows?
Or is there another method to refresh the item rows manually?
Thanks in advance
-Lukas

Comment: mCursor = getCursor();
mAdapter.changeCursor(mCursor);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Adapter's [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) method for that. This will make the listview refresh it's views.